# I want logstash to exit with a code 0 after processing all log files to mark Gitlab-ci Job as successful

Tags: logstash, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to configure a Gitlab-ci Job that collects logs from production servers and sends them to an elasticSearch server via a job that uses the Logstash docker image.

I know this is not the usual method, but we are not allowed to install Logstash on these servers!

The Job works well, but the problem is that we don't have the ability to specify a parameter to Logstash to exit with code 0 once the file processing is finished.

Gitlab-ci Job is therefore always running and stops with an error code when the maximum execution time is reached. The pipeline is marked as having failed even if the logs are well indexed in Elasticsearch!

Any idea how to solve or bypass this situation ?

Below is the Gitlab-ci job that runs Logstash

```
Job:Process:
  stage: process
  image: logstash:6.5.4
  dependencies:
    - Job:Getlogs
  script:
    - logstash -f config/logstash.conf
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English translation!

Answer (score 0):

A trick I've seen elsewhere is to pipe your logs into logstash, and use the `stdin` input to process them.

```
 cat /var/log/my_log | logstash -f my_config
```